# What is a Java ASM node?

Tags: java, nodes

I was recently looking into the [ASM API](http://asm.ow2.org/) and they use `Nodes` a lot. I've tried to find out what nodes really are, although I haven't come across any simple comprehensive answer. So, could someone explain in simple words what a node is and what it's used for?

*EDIT: I am asking what a node is in the context of the ASM API*

Comment: Just to make sure, you *are* only asking within the context of ASM API, right? Otherwise there could be a whole host of answers.

Comment: Yes, I am asking in the context of the ASM API.

Comment: I would guess that it's a node of the abstract syntax tree (AST) for a given bit of Java.

Comment: It would appear a node refers to a node in a (parse?) tree. See http://asm.ow2.org/doc/developer-guide.html and http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/package-summary.html

Comment: Nodes are elements of the data structure which represents the data in a `.class` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node` is used in an abstract sense. To understand their nodes, you must understand what a Node is in general.

A *network* is a group of items linked together. There are different ways these items can connect to one another, hence there are different types of networks.

A *node* is an item in that network. For example, a computer network:

```
            Client
          /
Server ---- Client
          \
            Client
```

There are 4 nodes in this network. 1 Server and 3 Clients. If you wanted, you can consider these as `ServerNode` and `ClientNode`.

Now, in the context of `ASM`, your network would be the code you are manipulating the bytecode of. Now that you know what your network is, distinquishing the nodes is pretty self-explanitory.

`MethodNode` represents a method. Looking at the documentation, you can see it has fields such as `String name` `String signature` and `int maxStack`. These are the properties of the specific method (MethodNode) you are viewing.

The term `Node` is the same throughout the API